# App layout wrong

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So when I run my app onto my tablet the layout is way off and to the top left i'm not sure why but in the preview its perfect here is my code please help. Sorry for the nooby question. I'm kinda new to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.thestickermafia.tsm.TSMCatagory"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/A_F"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/green"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="88dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/G_M"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/green"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="330dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="88dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/N_S"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/green"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="351dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/T_Z"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/green"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="330dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="350dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Font"
        android:layout_width="521dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/orange"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="610dp" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_viewr"
        android:layout_width="520dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search Ghrapics"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried another layout? or even tried changing the layout width?

Comment: Adding a screenshot to your post may help us solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constraints to each `View` in your layout. The `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` and `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY` values apply only to the design view. See this [reference](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constraints-overview).

Specifically:

> When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it stays where you leave it even if it has no constraints. However, this is only to make editing easier; if a view has no constraints when you run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).